# "Next" doesn't work when call binding.pry from eval(...)

Tags: ruby, debugging, eval, pry

When i run script with binding.pry using eval() i see this error:

> Error: Cannot find local context. Did you use `binding.pry`?

test.rb:

```
require 'pry'

def a
  binding.pry
  puts 'Hello'
end

a
```

runner.rb:

```
script = File.read('test.rb')
eval script
```

output:

```
$ ruby runner.rb   
[1] pry(main)> next 
Error: Cannot find local context. Did you use `binding.pry`?
[2] pry(main)> continue 
Error: Cannot find local context. Did you use `binding.pry`?
[3] pry(main)>
```

I need to call binding.pry from script, but I can't edit runner.rb

```
$ gem list
...
pry (0.10.4)
pry-byebug (3.4.2)
...

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. For me the solution was embarrassingly simple: just update the `pry-nav` gem to the latest version. For my case, the Ruby version had been recently upgraded, but the `pry*` gems had not yet been. Perhaps re-installing the gems can also alleviate the problem.